# Count the no. of occurrence and display the most repeated first no. followed by others. for Eg. input: 223331544 output: 32415

Tags: java

A program in Java that should count the no. of occurrence  and display the most repeated first no. followed by others. for eg. input: 223331544 output: 32415

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            boolean isDistinct = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    isDistinct = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isDistinct) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a `HashSet` ?

Comment: Use Set for this, Set is the simple and easy way to solve this issue

Comment: I don't think using a Set is the purpose of the OP. Seems more like an algorthmic exercise. However, the code should work like this even if it is not optimal. What's wrong so ?

Comment: Please refer to this article on Oracle about HashSet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 2):

The following code will print out distinct numbers:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

But this is not the answer. The requirement is to remove all the numbers that appear more than once. To do that, make a `Map` that containts the number as key and occurrence as value. While put the numbers into the `Map`, if the number is already exists, `+1` the occurrence. So the code is like the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3 };
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i : arr) {
            if (m.get(i) == null)
                m.put(i, 1);
            else
                m.put(i, m.get(i) + 1);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue() == 1)
                System.out.print(e.getKey() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. Output of your sol is [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8] . But 2 and 7 should not be printed.

Comment: This is now what is asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution for your problem.

```
import java.util.*;
class Hello    
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        int[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  set.add(arr[i]);
}

//now if you will iterate through this set, it will contain only unique values. 
Iterator it = set.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(it.next());
}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way

```
  public static void main(String a[]) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,2,3,4,5,5};
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        boolean isDistinct = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i!=j) {
                isDistinct = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isDistinct) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Out put:

```
1 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinkd Set already can help u do this, advanced Link.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

Use set

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class NonDuplicateElement{

     public static void main(String []args){

        int[] arr = {5,2,7,2,4,7,8,2,3};
        Set<Integer>set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer>remset = new HashSet<Integer>();        


        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(set.contains(arr[i]))
            {               
                remset.add(arr[i]);
            }
            else
            {               
                set.add(arr[i]);    
            }          

        }


        Iterator<Integer> iter = remset.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            Integer element = iter.next();
            if(set.contains(element))
            {
                set.remove(element);
            }
        }
        iter = set.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iter.next()+ "\t");
        }       

     }
}
```

**Output :** 3  4   5   8